# Internal resistance of a battery?

Tags: batteries, resistance

[image: Circuit scheme of a battery]

The task is to find \$I_L\$ and \$R_i\$ given \$U_L\$ and \$R_L\$.

\$I_L\$ is simple enough but I can't get my mind around how to find \$R_i\$ surely you must have more information?

Comment: What are the known values? Battery voltage?

Comment: Well, Ohm's law can tell you the current through \$R_L\$ with the known values, and then the current in the rest of the circuit must be...

Comment: @AdrianElder As stated, given values are \$U_L\$ and \$R_L\$

Comment: You can determine Il from Ul and Rl. In order to determine Ri you need more information. Indeed with the given information Ri cannot be determined. You can get more information by doing something with RL. Shorting it and measuring the ... or removing Rl and measuring the ... will give you the required information.

Comment: If this is a school study/homework (so you need to solve on paper) then you can't find with the info given. If not, remove RL and measure open voltage. This will give you E.

Comment: Everything you wanted to know (and a lot more) about batteries is at Battery University: [How to Measure Internal Resistance](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_measure_internal_resistance)

Comment: Those square-wave shaped symbols look like **memristors**... are they actually just resistors?

Comment: Just give a symbolic answer. In other words, show the equation used to calculate Ri.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you cannot completely answer the question with what is given.

You could fully answer the question if you disconnected the load resistor and measured the open circuit voltage.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Sure, it is very simple. All you need is a big and powerful variable resistor (few kW) and voltmeter and amp meter. Then you measure volts, amps with different load, but for very short time, because the current will be very high depending on type of the battery. The you do a V/I chart and you will find out that battery output voltage is decreasing with the load almost like straight line. Few basic calculations will give you the internal resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYvE3H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You actually need a Ri=ΔV/ΔI ratio or \$\dfrac{U1-U2}{I2-I1} =  Ri\$, *not just a load voltage*

Of course \$R_L\$ helps compute I1,I2 from U1/R1,U2/ R2.

Actually @Marko I think the slope you show is the reduction of charge in the equivalent capacitance. dV/dt=Ic/C and not Ri

Note in the graph below they this and show the negative V spike grows as the slope C reduces implying the ESR*C =T product tends to remain constant as the battery discharges and the ESR or Ri rises at the same time the voltage drops with a new slope.

[image]

Note that ESR above (or Ri) uses a steady current I1=10mA and a pulse current I2=500mA. Thus Ri=(V1-V2)/(500-10)mA

The dual slopes of batteries show a "double-layer" effect found in Supercaps. Yet batteries are 1k bigger C values than Supercaps (even Ultracaps which are same but may have lower ESR*C =T values. )

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjUSED.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>